# Sending notification to specific user account in iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, notifications, ionic2

Not sure if this is a correct spot to ask this question. Please let me know and I will remove the question.

Question:
I have an application that needs to send notification to individual User Phone. User needs to login to the application. ( Like Facebook ) and then upon an event, I need to send a notification to that specific account.

I wonder what do I search for on Internet. Can someone please give me a direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For iOS your should register for remote notification and get the device token on your phone within the App. And then you bind your device token for push notification with the your account, store the bind device token in your app backend server. Your backend server could use the device token associated with the account to send push notifications the that account by invoking APNS service provided by Apple. 
For Android it's similar to iOS, but you have much choices provide by Google and 3rd party services.

Answer (score 0):

For Android these links might help you out. [Android Push Notification using GCM Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-push-notification-using-gcm-tutorial/)
or this [Firebase Cloud Messaging Tutorial for Android](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/)